# How to write optimized reducer in awk

Tags: optimization, hadoop, dictionary, awk, reduce

I have below awk reducer program which works well while counting the values in key value pair.

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {FS="\t";
}
{       A[$1]+=$2;      
}
END {
        for(i in A)    
        {printf("%s\t %d\n" ,i ,A[i])}
}
```

Above reducer works well, is there any optimized way to write it...?

Input:

```
APPLE 1
APPLE 1
 1
ORANGE  1
ORANGE  1
MANGO 1
BANANA 1
 1
 1
 1
ORANGE  1
 1
APPLE 1
BANANA 1
```

Output:

```
APPLE 3
BANANA 2
MANGO 1
ORANGE 3
 5
```

Comment: you'll need to add addtional infomation about why you think this isn't optimized. If you want to be able to output data in a different order, rather than the abitrary version that you'll get from using `for(i in A)`, you'll have to **specify the output you do want by editing your question** . Good luck.

Comment: I am expecting  a code like in answer 2. But that is giving error in reducer phase. Can you give me some solution like answer 2

Comment: Your sample input is faulty. The Hadoop framework would group all tuples with the same key together. For example, your input shows the "APPLE" key at the beginning and then again close to the end of the input. That would not happen. All tuples with "APPLE" as a key would be together, with no other keys in between.

Comment: Above input is  from mapper to reducer through hadoop streaming api. I just copied mapper result above as input. I am trying this reducer code in hadoop cluster by streaming api.

Comment: Chris' answer is exactly what you want and it should work fine. Why do you think it is not working? What results do you get?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your definition of optimized - you current solution is limited in that it has to maintain the entire result set in an associative array. An alternative approach would be to compare the field 1 to the previous value, and update a count if they match, otherwise output the previous value and count. With this method you can output results as you go. I don't know the performance costs in using this algorithm, but like i said previously, it isn't memory limited:

```
BEGIN {
  FS = "\t";
  OFS = "\t";
}
{ 
  if ($1 != prev) { 
    if (prev != "") { print prev, count;} 
    prev=$1; 
    count=0;
  }
  count += $2 
}
END { 
  print prev, count
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am exactly looking for this kind of solution but unfortunately for the above code  I am getting error in reducer phase.

Comment: Sorry, i used single quotes instead of double quotes in the BEGIN section - i've updated the snippet above to reflect this

Comment: Still code is not working. For your reference i added sample input and expected output in question. Input contains a empty string as key

Comment: Are you testing this code in a real Hadoop installation, or are you testing it (without Hadoop) in bash with your sample input? If you are doing the latter, it may not work because your sample input is faulty. All tuples with the same Key will be sent together (one after the other) to the reducer. Your sample input shows the same key appearing sparsely in the input.

Comment: Oh, and to fix the issue of the empty string as key, you can do this: add `prev = "SOMETHING_THAT_WILL_NEVER_BE_A_KEY"` to the `BEGIN` block, and then change `if (prev != "")` to `if (prev != "SOMETHING_THAT_WILL_NEVER_BE_A_KEY")`.

Comment: I'm with @cabad if you're input to the reducer isn't sorted then you're not in a reducer. How is it not 'working' - is there an error or just the wrong output. The script works for some sample input i piped through the script

Comment: I made changes specified by cabad but still not working.Above input is from mapper to reducer through hadoop streaming api. I just copied mapper result above as input. I am trying this reducer code in hadoop cluster by streaming api. Where i can see hadoop-streaming api logs..?

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN {FS="\t"; OFS="\t "}
{ A[$1]+=$2 }
END {
    for(i in A)    
        print i, A[i]
}
```

Of course, there may be alternatives depending on your input data and what kind of optimization you're actually looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , above code exactly does the same like my above code.But I am looking for code like below post but that is throwing error.

Comment: @NagarajVittal - did you downvote this??? You asked for optimized code and that's what I gave you. It's briefer and should run faster due to using print instead of printf.

Comment: I am not down voting your answer but not getting another way of optimized code to compare performance.